# A question on $n$-divisible group for some $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $X$ be an abelian group and $G$ a divisible subgroup of $X$.
Let $L$ be a subgroup of $X$ such that $nL\subseteq G$ for some $n$.
Is $L/L[n]$ $n$-divisible? ($L[n]$ denotes the subgroup $\{x\in L; nx=0\}$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a divisible group and let $G=X$ and let $L$ be a finite subgroup of $X$. Then $nL \subset G$ for every $n$ and $L/L[n]$ is a finite group. But a nontrivial finite group cannot be divisible, therefore $L[n]=L$ for every $n$ hence $L=\{0\}$.

To get a contradiction, it is sufficient to find a divisible group containing a nontrivial finite subgroup, a Prüfer group for example.

For an explicit counterexample, take $X=G= \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$ and $L=X[p^2]= \{x \in X \mid p^2x=0\}$. Then $pL \subset G$ and $L/L[p] \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}^{\times}$.